# How do you extract part of an NSUserDefault to put into a UITableView, UIButton text or even a UILabel?

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, nsstring, xml-parsing

I have cached the contents of a url using the following method and have saved the text as an NSUserDefault as I need to access it in another UIViewController.

This is the code that I am using to download the contents of a URL and save as an NSUserDefault and this is the code that I am using to load the contents of that NSUserDefault into a UITableView.

//Downloading URLcontents and save to an NSUser Default

```
NSString *url = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.pharmacon.site50.net/database/1.xml"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *myTxtFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myTxtFile forKey:@"one"];
```

//Loading an NSUserDefault and placing it in a UITextView

```
NSString *myTxtFile = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"one"];
textView.text=myTxtFile;
```

Here is what a typical XML file looks like that I have downloaded;

```
<item>
<din>1</din>
<category>Drugs</category>
<name>Paracetamol</name>
<phonetic>Pa-ra-ce-ta-mol</phonetic>
<spoken>Paracetamol.mp3</spoken>
<description>
Paracetamol is a drug commonly used for headaches and minor aches and pains.
</description>
<purpose>
Paracetamol is best used for minor to moderate aches and pains and can also be used to treat mild headaches.
</purpose>
<author>Sam Vale</author>
<editor>Harrison Fuller</editor>
</item>
```

Now, what I want to be able to do is read this NSUserDefault but actually extract just the text in the name region (so in this case, "Paracetamol) and then put that into the text of a UITableView cell, as the text of a button or a UILabel (choose whichever you reckon would be best or what you know).The reason I want to do this is cause I am going to display results that I download off the database in a UITableView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need `NSXMLParser` for this. There's plenty of examples on how to use it to parse XML available on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would vote up your response but I only have 10 for my reputation as I am new to Stack Overflow and you need a 15 for reputation to be able to vote up.